# How to display tags inline?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

How can I display tags below an article inline? I have tried using firebug to no avail. I am using Drupal 7 and the zen sub theme.

Comment: put a link to ur site here for us to have a look at it

Comment: my website is not yet live as i am still developing it. however, when i added tags on a test article, they aligned vertically. i want them to align horizontally similar to how they appear on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS to style the tags.

If your html output is this:

```
<ul class="tags">
    <li>Tag 1</l1>
    <li>Tag 2</l1>
    <li>Tag 3</l1>
    <li>Tag 4</l1>
</ul>
```

Then use the following CSS to align tags horizontally.

```
.tags li { display:block; float:left; }
```

Comment: or you can use **.tags li { display:inline-block; }**

Comment: I agree, that would work too.